# Out Of Memory error while converting large HTML file to PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, flying-saucer, openhtmltopdf

I am working on an assignment wherein I need to create an HTML file and convert the HTML file to PDF. I am using Thymeleaf and flying-saucer-pdf to get this done. The Thymeleaf part works fine and creates the HTML file. However, the PDF creation part fails with out-of-memory error. The HTML file that gets created is around 275 MB and has around 8000000 lines.

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("outFile.pdf")
String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("data.html")));

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
// renderer.setDocument(new File("data.html"));

renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
renderer.finishPDF();
outputStream.close();
```

the execution gets stuck in the **renderer.layout()** for a long time and then fails.
I tried both **renderer.setDocumentFromString** and renderer.setDocument and the results are the same.
Also, i tried **com.openhtmltopdf** for PDF generation from HTML and it also resulted in Out Of Memory error.

```
String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("data.html")));
  Document document = Jsoup.parse(html, "UTF-8");
  document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);

  try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("outFile.pdf")) {
      PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
      builder.withUri("outFile.pdf");
      builder.toStream(os);
      builder.withW3cDocument(new W3CDom().fromJsoup(document), "/");
      builder.run();
  }
```

Wondering whether there are any alternate libraries or buffered logic that take care of the memory issue. Any help and pointers are much appriciated.